# Jquery está carregando apenas no primeiro item da tabela

Tags: php, jquery, loop, tabela-html

Bom dia,

Tenho uma tabela que exibe os orçamentos (vindo do banco) dentro de um loop while...

Para cada orçamento há o botão de visualizar mais detalhes, em que abre um modal

E nesse modal, é inserido nos inputs os valores de cada produto e

uma função jquery efetua o calculo com o valor total e exibe.

-
Porém o problema está em ele efetuar esse calculo, em toda a tabela.

Apenas no primeiro elemento da tabela, ele funciona perfeitamente!

Porém já nas outras linhas da tabela, simplesmente não carrega a soma, nem mostra nada no console,

O modal abre em todos, com as informações corretas, apenas a função de soma que não...

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como executar isso?

(já tive o msm problema com modal de editar produto, porém acabei exibindo em outra página mesmo, 
pois não encontro nada sobre e não consegui desenvolver nada

já tentei abrir o modal com o jquery passando com a id do modal, porém também não funciona...)

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens?

Comment: O problema pode estar na construção da função! Talvez utilizou como "chave de ignição da função" um ID em vez de CLASS. O que iria impedir! Isso é só uma observação! Mas pra melhor resposta, é só fazendo o que o Sérgio disse! Posta aqui seu código!

Comment: coloque o código html e javascript por favor